# Re-compose a Tensor after tensor factorization

Tags: python, math, data-science, scikits

I am trying to decompose a 3D matrix using python library [scikit-tensor](https://github.com/mnick/scikit-tensor). I managed to decompose my Tensor (with dimensions 100x50x5) into three matrices. My question is how can I compose the initial matrix again using the decomposed matrix produced with Tensor factorization? I want to check if the decomposition has any meaning. My code is the following:

```
import logging
from scipy.io.matlab import loadmat
from sktensor import dtensor, cp_als
import numpy as np

//Set logging to DEBUG to see CP-ALS information
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
T = np.ones((400, 50))
T = dtensor(T)
P, fit, itr, exectimes = cp_als(T, 10, init='random')
// how can I re-compose the Matrix T? TA = np.dot(P.U[0], P.U[1].T)
```

I am using the canonical decomposition as provided from the scikit-tensor library function cp_als. Also what is the expected dimensionality of the decomposed matrices?

Comment: cp.py says:  $A\approx\sum_{r=1}^{rank} \\vec{u}_r^{(1)} \outer \cdots \outer \\vec{u}_r^{(N)}$. Have you tried that? This should be identical to "P.totensor()"

Comment: @Bort you mean the lines 145 and 146 of cp.py?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The CP product of, for example, 4 matrices

[image: X_{abcd} = \displaystyle\sum_{z=0}^{Z}{A_{az} B_{bz} C_{cz} D_{dz} + \epsilon_{abcd}}]

can be expressed using [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) as

[image: X_{abcd} = A_{az} B_{bz} C_{cz} D_{dz} + \epsilon_{abcd}]

or in numpy as

```
numpy.einsum('az,bz,cz,dz -> abcd', A, B, C, D)
```

so in your case you would use

```
numpy.einsum('az,bz->ab', P.U[0], P.U[1])
```

or, in your 3-matrix case

```
numpy.einsum('az,bz,cz->abc', P.U[0], P.U[1], P.U[2])
```

`sktensor.ktensor.ktensor` also have a method `totensor()` that does exactly this:

```
np.allclose(np.einsum('az,bz->ab', P.U[0], P.U[1]), P.totensor())
>>> True
```

Comment: Hey Nils thanks for the reply. Are you sure about this? I tried to re-compose the matrix and the result was not close to the intial tensor.

Comment: Well, it depends on how nicely you can decompose the tensor in the first place. If your epsilon is big the two will be noticeably different.

Comment: What are the parameters except the number of latent dimension I can handle in the case of cp_als algorithm?

Comment: I don't understand your question, sorry.

Comment: I am trying to figure out what are the parameters I can tune during the decomposition except the tensor rank.

Comment: The parameters are [in the docstring](https://github.com/mnick/scikit-tensor/blob/master/sktensor/cp.py#L46).

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

See an explanation of CP [here](https://github.com/rmsolgi/TensorLearn/tree/main/CP_decomposition). You may also use [tensorlearn](https://pypi.org/project/tensorlearn/) package to rebuild the tensor.